# Rails route globbing for CORS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors

I'm implementing CORS on a rails API and I basically want a to define a route that says "All requests to API calls via the OPTIONS method should go to the controller action `cors`".

The relavant parts of what I have so far:

```
# routes.rb:
scope :module => 'api', :path => 'api' do
  match '*', :action => 'cors', :constraints => { :method => 'OPTIONS' }
end

# base_api_controller.rb:
class Api::BaseApiController < ApplicationController
  def cors
    # ... setting headers of Access-Control-Allow-Origin and stuff here...
  end
end
```

The problem I'm hitting is when I make the request via javascript, I get the error:

```
OPTIONS <url> Resource failed to load
```

It seems like this should be working and that I'm just missing something simple.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want requests to go through a "controller action cors" and not the default api/ controller but here's how you could do it

```
#Gemfile
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'

#config/application.rb
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins "*"
    resource "/api/*", :headers => :any, :methods => [:options], :action => 'cors'
  end
end
```

Alternatively **I wouldn't send this to a different controller action** so this is actually what i think you want

```
#Gemfile
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'

#config/application.rb
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins "*"
    resource "/api/*", :headers => :any, :methods => [:options]
  end
end
```